# Code in TypeScript working in local, but not working in production

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, angular-ng-if

```
<div>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <button class="btnClass">{{ submitButtonCaption }}</button>
    <button type="button" style="margin-left:15px;" class="cancelButton" (click)="clearSearch()">
      {{ clearButtonCaption }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Local system this code is working fine, but in the server showing like below:

```
<div>
    <!--bindings={    
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"    
    }-->​
</div>
```

Angular 7 project: so in TypeScript file `@component` template section inline, I have written this code between `` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You have some *ngIf directive which resolves to false. I cannot tell much more without whole code to review.